# Google Analytics how to view exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, google-analytics

I would like to track exceptions via the Google Analytics.

I have the following code

```
ga('send', 'exception', {
  'exDescription': 'Error',
  'exFatal': true,
  'appName': 'test',
  'appVersion': '1.0'
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to view this information in the admin console og GA. I tried to make a custom report but it is always empty.

Any ideas guys? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are probably **watching classic "desktop/HTML/JavaScript"** property, where Exceptions do not exists.

You have to **Create new property**. There is a question "What would you like to track" -> **Choose: Mobile App.**

Since this, you will have accessible **Crashes and Exceptions** under Behaviour report.